# Cannot resolve symbol 'adapter'

Tags: android, android-layout, android-adapter

I receive an error with the following code. I don't understand why, but `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` doesn't work. The message of error is: "cannot resolve symbol 'adapter'".

```
final String URL = "http://example....";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    rv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv);

    ....

    public class PrintA extends AsyncTask<String, String, List<Model>> {
        ....
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final List<MyModel> result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if (result != null) {
                MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(result);
                rv.setAdapter(adapter);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "no internet",                
            }
        }
    }

    new PrintA().execute(URL);

    rv.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        ....
        public class PrintB extends AsyncTask<String, String, List<Model>> {
            ....

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(final List<MyModel> result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                if (result != null) {
                    ....
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "can't add",                
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                ....            
                new PrintB().execute(URL);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is no different than any of the other cannot find symbol errors that have been asked about on this website.

Comment: `adapter` is a local variable within the `onPostExecute()` method of `PrintA`. It cannot be referenced anywhere outside of that method.

Answer (score 1):

```
  MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(result);
```

replace this by

```
  adapter = new MyAdapter(result);
```

and declare this in Global

```
 MyAdapter adapter;
```

like this

```
 MyAdapter adapter;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
```

Comment: And so how can I push 'result' in adapter(in PrintB)? I tried with add,(..), but don't work now.

Comment: You need to stop being vague. What do you mean by "don't work"? Error? Exception? Wrong output?

Comment: Yes sorry, i can not add new elements (contained in 'result') in recyclerview.

Comment: I know it works, because if I do 'rv.setAdapter (adapter);' again, I see the content charging again.